# Callback into singleton class

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton

I am using a singleton class with a thread that calls into the singleton. I was asked during a review why I used the this pointer instead of the singleton instance.

My code with the suggested changes.

```
class myClass : public threadWrapper
{
public:
    static myClass& instance()
    {
        static myClass instance;
        return instance;
    }

    // This is the callback that I have implemented
    static void callback(void *me)
    {
        if (me != NULL)
            static_cast<myClass*>(me)->doCallback();
    }

    // This is the suggested callback
    static void callback2(void *me)
    {
        instance().doCallback();
    }

    // caller gets instance and then calls initialise()
    int initialise()
    {  
        if (initialised)
            return ERROR_ALREADY_INITIALISED;

        // Initialise the class

        // my thread startup call
        // thread wrapper class initialisation that calls pthread_create that runs the callback method with this as a parameter
        // priority is a global value that difines the relative priority of the various threads.
        threadWrapper::Initialise(priority, callback, this);
        initialised = true;

    }
private:
    myClass() : initialised(false) {;}

    void doCallback(void);

    bool initialised;

    static const int 
}
```

So is there any significant difference in speed between the two?

The threadWrapper is mandated in the existing code base, and I'm not allowed to use boost.

My justification was that if we needed to make this not a singleton then fewer changes would be required.

Comment: AFAIK that `static_cast` should not work. It should be a `reinterpret_cast` and i'd prefer the solution with the `this` pointer exactly for the reason you provided (easier to port to non singleton class). IMHO there should be no speed gains/losses from this change.

Comment: You know what would require even less changes to make it a not singleton? Not making it a singleton in the first place.

Comment: @RedX: The static_cast is correct for casting void* to SomeType*

Comment: @John Ideone agrees with you. I learned something today thx.

Comment: @John: As long as it was originally cast from SomeType* (as is the case here) and not a pointer to a type derived from SomeType.  Have to be careful if inheritance is involved.

Comment: @ToddR: static_cast will compile either way. *You* have to be careful, because the compiler won't be.

Answer (score 5):

The speed difference will be pretty much nonexistent.

As for code quality, Singletons are quite horrendous and I personally would chuck out both forms, *especially* in a threaded environment. Assuming that it's too late for that, however.

The thing is, if you're gonna pass in a pointer to the object, why not just not make that object global in the first place?  And if you are, it should at least be strongly typed. And then, you're just ... wrapping a member method in a static method? Why bother? Anyone who has a pointer to the class can just call the method on it in the first place. This is just insane.

Edit: If you're stuck with the existing design, then the second version is *definitely* better than the first and no slower. Even if you have existing code that depends on the Singleton, then it's absolutely better to refactor what you can to not depend on it.

Comment: This is the standard idiom when interfacing with C libraries that pass an opaque void pointer to your callback function.

Comment: @user786653: Except instead of doing that, he *could* just take a `boost::function<void()>` to use as the thread function. Or just use `boost::thread`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to defend the choice here, just noting how this otherwise 'insane' looking piece of code could have come about.

Comment: As I just added to the question, the threadWrapper is mandated in an existing project and boost is not allowed. This may change but until it does I'm stuck with what I've got.

Comment: @DanS: If you're stuck with poor legacy code like that, then what you've done is definitely better and for the best.